# Pydio Cells Plugins

Tags: go, pydio

I need to extend/customize a Pydio Cells v2 deployment and am looking for informations on how to write and deploy plugins for Pydio Cells. Sadly I cannot find any informations about that. All I can find is infos about the "old" Pydio. Could anyone give me some hints please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [developer guide](https://pydio.com/en/docs/developer-guide), but it seems to be only for the REST APIs. It's still  unclear where you put the logic and all that. IIRC they also said the microservice architecture could be language agnostic.

So far I couldn't find any tutorial. That's too bad for such a promising project.